# Creating static framework for OS X

Tags: xcode, macos

With the use of a [mild hack](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework), it is possible to make *static frameworks* for iOS. Static frameworks are quite convenient to use: they can simply be dropped into new projects without extra steps (like adding them to the build and adding header search paths).

I've recently started doing OS X programming, and the first thing I noticed was that static frameworks don't seem to be available. Dynamic frameworks are obviously available and recommended, but as I want to make a little private framework intended for application use (not installation in `/Library/Frameworks`), using a dynamic framework in new application projects still [requires a bunch of extra steps](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002258-SW1).

In my ideal world, I'd create a static framework (a framework which contains header files and a compiled `.a` file), drag & drop the framework onto a new project, and start coding. Is there any way to make such a static framework on OS X?

P.S. I already tried setting the Mach-O output type to "static library" in a normal framework project, but I just get the error `Framework target has invalid MACH_O_TYPE value of 'staticlib'.`.

Comment: Static libraries are not really a thing on OS X. They're only used on iOS because dynamic loading is difficult (maybe even impossible?) in signed apps. Use dynamic frameworks, following the instructions you linked to.

Comment: "Static libraries are not really a thing on OS X." that's... not true.

Comment: Why not just build a static library?

Comment: @mipadi: I could, but static frameworks are a lot nicer. You drop them on a project, and the necessary headers and libraries are automatically added to the project. By contrast, with a static library, you either have to install the library to a system directory like `/usr/` or you have to add the include directories and library files manually.

Comment: @nneonneo: A static library gets linked into the executable at compile time, so there's no need to install the library or package it with the application.

Comment: @mipadi: This is about making it easier for developers to integrate the library.

Comment: @nneonneo: How is it difficult to use a static library in a project?

Comment: @mipadi: Like I said, there's a lot more setup to do. If I want to make a library that people can use easily with minimal setup, a static framework is faster and simpler, and less error-prone. It's just a better alternative to a static library from a usability standpoint (and this matters: I was originally aiming to produce a library that could be used by beginners).

Comment: @nneonneo: How is it better, though? With a static library, you pretty much just drop the compiled library into the Xcode project and go. The drawback is that you can't package resource files with it, but if you only have code, it really doesn't get any simpler than that.

Comment: @mipadi: and what do you do with headers? You have to go and add the headers to the project settings, in the target settings. And yes, resources don't get included, and that's a definite downside too.

Comment: @nneonneo: I don't know if it's all that hard for Mac developers to drag a few header files into a project, but I suppose you can use Cocoapods if you want it to be really easy.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dynamic framework on Mac OS X. In your dynamic framework you can set the LD_DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME as @rpath/Foo.framework/Versions/A/Foo

If you have an app that wants to link with this framework then you make sure you run the

```
  install_name_tool -add_rpath <rpath> <full-path-to-app-binary>
```

So if I had Foo.app

```
  install_name_tool -add_rpath Foo.app/Contents/Library Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo
```

Now if you just copy your Foo.framework into Contents/Library it should get loaded and everything should work.

I hope this helps.

Probably simpler would be to use a static library with public headers. When you build the static lib you can have Xcode copy the headers for you automatically. And in your target you can add the folder to your search path.

If you use a static library Xcode will strip away some dead code that your app doesn't really need but is compiled into the static lib.

Comment: ...`you can have Xcode copy the headers for you automatically.`. This actually sounds very close to what I want. How do I do this? Can I just have Xcode copy them to a system directory?

Comment: You can just have Xcode copy headers into the build folder. If I am not wrong your build directory is part of the header search path.

Answer (score 1):

Static frameworks aren't really supported on OS X. They're fairly brittle anyway, and solve a specific problem that exists on iOS but not on OS X.

If you're looking to make it easy for developers to use a library you create, you have a couple options:

1. Use [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org). They have a [tutorial](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/index.html) for publishing your library on CocoaPods. This is probably the easiest way to distribute a library on OS X.
2. Package your library as a framework. If you set the install name correctly (to `@rpath/<library name>`), the downstream developer merely needs to copy the framework into their Xcode project and set the runtime search path of their application to `@executable_path/../Frameworks`).